# To add an attribute value for all child nodes after root tag in XML Flex

Tags: xml, apache-flex

Am unable to add an attribute to the child nodes like how you did for grand child nodes.How to do this.I had used

```
for each(var node:XML in valueXml.item)
{          
  for(var j:int=0; j<valueXml.length(); j++)
  {
     node.@name = valueXml.item[j].item[0].@name;
  }
}
```

From the old xml:

```
<item>
  <item name="Subchild1"/>
  <item name="leaf1"/>
  <item name="leaf2"/>
</item>
<item>
  <item name="Subchild2"/>
  <item name="leaf3"/>
  <item name="leaf4"/>
</item>
```

I need to add it as follows:

```
 <root>
   <item name="Subchild1">
     <item name="Subchild1"/>
     <item name="leaf1"/>
     <item name="leaf2"/>
   </item>
 <item name="Subchild2">
     <item name="Subchild2"/>
     <item name="leaf3"/>
     <item name="leaf4"/>
 </item>
```

I want to add the first sub-child([Subchild2,leaf3,leaf4]) of each child node("Subchild2") as the attribute name to that child node.How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

//your xml

```
        private var xml:XML = new XML(
            <root>
                <item>
                  <item name="Subchild1"/>
                  <item name="leaf1"/>
                  <item name="leaf2"/>
                </item>
                <item>
                  <item name="Subchild2"/>
                  <item name="leaf3"/>
                  <item name="leaf4"/>
                </item>
            </root>
        );
```

// the function

```
    for each (var node:XML in xml.item)
    {
        var attrName:String = node.item[0].@name;
        node.@name = attrName;
    }
```

//trace gives:

```
<root>
  <item name="Subchild1">
    <item name="Subchild1"/>
    <item name="leaf1"/>
    <item name="leaf2"/>
  </item>
  <item name="Subchild2">
    <item name="Subchild2"/>
    <item name="leaf3"/>
    <item name="leaf4"/>
  </item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you are at the node you want to add the attribute to, you can simply assign it the value from the name of its firstchild.

```
var xml:XML = new XML(<root>
  <item>
    <item name="Subchild1"/>
    <item name="leaf1"/>
    <item name="leaf2"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <item name="Subchild2"/>
    <item name="leaf3"/>
    <item name="leaf4"/>
  </item>
 </root>);


for each (var item:XML in xml.item) {
  item.@name = item.children()[0].@name;
}
```